# Член класса, который возвращает ссылку на объект этого же класс

Tags: c++

Допустим если класс `Date` и  член этого класса `fun`, который должен вернуть ссылку на объект этого класса:

```
class Date {
    Date &fun();
};
```

Как правильно записать прототип функции, перед тем как написать ее тело? Т.е., когда я пишу

```
Date::Date &fun()
{
}
```

Проверка указывает, что это должен быть конструктор... Как правильно оформить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date & Date::fun ()
{
}
```

То есть функция `Date::fun`, которая имеет тип `Date &`

Но правильнее говорить -- метод класса.

Comment: а, ну да, че-то я затупил

Comment: C++ как раз оперирует термином «функция-член», а не «метод». А «методов класса» в плюсах как таковых нет.... Но, в разговорной речи и то и другое использовать ИМХО вполне допустимо...

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ошибся.

Comment: При возврате ссылки на объект особое внимание также стоит уделить времени жизни этого объекта, чтобы не возникло ситуации с возвратом ссылки на локальный объект

Answer (score 1):

Date &Date::fun()
Не пробовали?